# Retrofitting Rusted Deck Standoff

Tags: deck, retrofit

I have a very rusted 4 x 4 deck standoff:

Is it possible to retrofit this post without having to move the entire post? I was hoping I could jack up the deck and cut the bolt off and then make new holes (securing the standoff to the concrete with [1/2" sleeve anchors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hilti-1-2-in-x-3-in-Hex-Nut-Head-HLC-Sleeve-Anchors-5-Pack-3512340/204993035)) without having to move anything.

I found [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-E-Z-Base-Black-Powder-Coated-Post-Base-for-4x4-Nominal-Lumber-FPBB44/100655350?MERCH=REC-_-Pip_Alternatives_Non_HDhome-_-205694616-_-100655350-_-N)
product, but it appears to be specifically for fences. Does something like this exist for decks? I want to make sure everything is up to code.

[link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMuBc.jpg)

[image]

Comment: If the wood is rotted, and you have some carpentry skills, you can still rescue the post.   Tom Silva does it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6naaDBrZSc

Answer (score 1):

There are several versions of that type of bracket available.

It is called a post base bracket.
My local home improvement centers carry them.

[Here is one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/b002v0tpdu)

It is fastened to the concrete with nut and bolt.
You may have problem when you remove yours as the nut and bolt are probably rusted like the bracket.

I would spray them with [PB Blaster](https://blastercorp.com/product/pb-blaster-penetrant/) several times over a couple of days, heat it with a torch and wack the top of it with a hammer before you try to remove the nut.

If you break the bolt off you have a problem dealing with a steel bolt in the exact spot you need to drill for installing a new bolt/anchor. It *may* be easier to relocate the post if that happens.

You will need a temporary post to support the structure while you remove the old post and replace the bracket.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, that base would allow a post to be slid into position after the plate is secure. You should be able to swing the post enough to make that happen.